# Google Analytics - Why do some of my visits report 0 Pages / Visit?

Tags: google-analytics

I've currently looking at my Google Analytics statistics for Berlin and I can see that I have 1 Visit but 0 Pages / Visit. Is this just some blip in the GA software - or is this likely to be a problem in my code? I can't see think how someone could have visited my site without visiting one of its pages.

(This is a fairly uncommon problem, I should say. I've just noticed it now and then and was wondering what the cause of it could be.)

Answer (score 0):

You have some other kind of hits.

The types of hits in GA are:

- Pageviews (`_trackPageview`)
- Events (`_trackEvent`)
- Social Interactions (`_trackSocial`)
- Custom timming (`_trackTimming`)
- Set Var (`_setVar`) *deprecated*
- Ecommerce items (`_addItem` + `_trackTrans`)
- Ecommerce trans (`_addTrans` + `_trackTrans`)

The most common is probably `_trackEvent`, check your events table and try to find out why some visits get events but no pageviews.

It can also be due to bad filtering rules. Some kind of rule that filter out pageviews from a profile but not other hit types, causing visits with only other hit types.

If you still use the old `_setVar` you can probably see the data inside the "User Defined" report, if that's the case, then it's time to remove these calls and move on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've just checked 'Events' though and found that the only Event Categories are 'page' and the only Event Actions are 'read-update' - so I'm guessing your first suggestion isn't the case.

I've checked my source code for `_setVar` too and not found anything, although I did find `Var` here. Don't know if that helps...?

Comment: In fact that event seem to confirm my theory. Where does that come from? Try to create a segment of visits with pageDepth=0 and look at the events table. If it has anything there it is.